# could not autowire field spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

Need some help, I am just starting to learn Spring and can't seem to figure out what us wrong:

Application.java - no package

```
@Configuration
//@ComponentScan({"com.mapping","com.accesors","com.controllers"}) --Originaly tried this
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses={UserDAO.class,Root.class,User.class})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

User.java - package com.mapping

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    //accesors
}
```

UserDAO.java - package com.accesors

```
@Repository
public interface UserDAO extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

Root.java - package com.controllers

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/*")
public class Root {

    @Autowired
    UserDAO userDAO;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    public String rootAction(@RequestParam(defaultValue="foo") String name){
        List<User> lst = this.userDAO.findAll();
        for(User u : lst){
            System.out.println(u);
        }
        return "hello, " + name;
    }

}
```

And I seem to get the following exeption when I run the project

Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'root': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.accesors.UserDAO com.controllers.Root.userDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.accesors.UserDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at demo.Application.main(Application.java:14)
```

From what I understand it means that @ComponentScan is not detecting the packages

Comment: So what implements `UserDao`?

Comment: @Makoto Nothing, it is Spring-Data-JPA see http://www.petrikainulainen.net/spring-data-jpa-tutorial/

Comment: If I recall, Spring-Data-JPA uses aspects to create the class at runtime

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your Spring Data repositories are not in a sub-package of the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` class then you need to add `@EnableJpaRepositories` (and ditto for `@EntityScan` if the entities are not in a sub-package).

Comment: This is brilliant. I originally thought including the package in @componentScan will do the trick.
But seems like you have to include repositories and entities out of base-package in the `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EntityScan` respectively. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are **testing** your springboot app with springRunner don't forget to include the ComponentScan annotation.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)    
@SpringBootTest (classes = YourRestController.class )    
@ComponentScan({"your package goes here"})    
@AutoConfigureMockMvc    
@ActiveProfiles("development")    
public class Foo{
}
```