# Run/Debug Spring Boot Application from IntelliJ Idea

Tags: rest, tomcat, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I have a Java 1.8 Spring Boot application with a REST interface serviced by Tomcat.  The application runs fine as a JAR from the command line. I created a Spring Boot Run/Debug Edit Configuration in IntelliJ and launched the debugger.

[image]

I get bean creation errors:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializerPostProcessor': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor.beanFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.jpa.outbound.JpaOutboundGatewayFactoryBean#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'findDebtorAccountGateway.jpaExecutor' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'findDebtorAccountGateway.jpaExecutor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.jpa.outbound.JpaOutboundGatewayFactoryBean#1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'findCreditorAccountGateway.jpaExecutor' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'findCreditorAccountGateway.jpaExecutor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:220)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:615)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at com.distributedfinance.mbi.MbiApplication.main(MbiApplication.java:19)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor.beanFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.jpa.outbound.JpaOutboundGatewayFactoryBean#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'findDebtorAccountGateway.jpaExecutor' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'findDebtorAccountGateway.jpaExecutor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.jpa.outbound.JpaOutboundGatewayFactoryBean#1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'findCreditorAccountGateway.jpaExecutor' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'findCreditorAccountGateway.jpaExecutor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.jpa.outbound.JpaOutboundGatewayFactoryBean#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'findDebtorAccountGateway.jpaExecutor' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'findDebtorAccountGateway.jpaExecutor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.jpa.outbound.JpaOutboundGatewayFactoryBean#1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'findCreditorAccountGateway.jpaExecutor' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'findCreditorAccountGateway.jpaExecutor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
```

I also just right clicked on the class and launched Run/Debug:
[image]

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializerPostProcessor': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor.beanFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.jpa.outbound.JpaOutboundGatewayFactoryBean#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'findDebtorAccountGateway.jpaExecutor' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'findDebtorAccountGateway.jpaExecutor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.jpa.outbound.JpaOutboundGatewayFactoryBean#1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'findCreditorAccountGateway.jpaExecutor' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'findCreditorAccountGateway.jpaExecutor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Have you seen [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24645853/could-not-autowire-field-spring-boot) ?

Comment: Ok.  Why would running from the debugger cause this problem but not running the .jar from the CLI?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not entirely certain, but I see this happening _all_ the time when doing my J2EE work.  IntelliJ loads classes in a certain way and the CLI also has its own way of doing things.

Comment: This was already in the App.context @EnableJpaRepositories("com.distributedfinance.mbi.repository")

Comment: Did you manually create that configuration? Have you tried just running it (right click class and run instead of creating a configuration)? I run my Spring Boot apps like that always without problems.

Comment: Yes, I manually created the Spring Boot edit configuration (Jet Brains' direction).  It also fails right clicking on class (see above).

Comment: maybe you are missing some annotations for some classes

Answer (score 1):

Resolved.  I had the wrong 'working directory' in Spring Boot edit configuration.